# How can I programmatically build a SOAP envelope response in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, response, operation

Like the title says I would like to know if it is possible to edit the SOAP envelope that is sent back to the client after a WCF operation?

Thanks in advance,

Tri

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using the Message class.  See this tutorial [here](http://csharping.com/wcf/building-a-soap-response-envelope-manually-with-the-message-class/) for a demonstration of how to use it.